# sed pattern command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

So I have this sed command applied on $1 wich is a file
what I'd like to know is how sed evaluates all the slash, backslash
succession and what does any character in the pattern mean

```
sed '/^\/\*/d/.*\*\//d' $1
```

as far as I know

```
'/^ ....../d'
```

deletes some pattern at the begining of line (considering the second d)

-what does the first d stand for, what about the dot and the / or /\ (unescape chars?)

could please someone explain this to me please ?

Comment: please read http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html . Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually two sed commands back to back:

```
/^\/\*/d
/.*\*\//d
```

`^` matches start of line, `\/` matches a literal forward-slash, `\*` matches a literal asterisk.  (Since forward-slash and asterisk are "meta-characters", they need to be escaped with a backslash to match literally.)

`.*` matches any sequence of characters, `\*` matches a literal asterisk again, `\/` matches a literal slash again.

Put it all together, and what this does is to delete C-style comments, but only if they appear at the start of a line:

```
/* This will go away */This will stay
```

Comment: i see so litteraly it deletes all the /*....*/ inline
if the /*....*/ changes to // i would simply have
/^\/\/\.*/d ?
what about if the comment extends on multiple lines (i would have to use some sort of delimiter or work out with some if's ?)

Comment: Yes, your example would delete from `//` to the end of the line, but only if it starts at the beginning of the line (because you anchored it with `^`).  I do not think you can use sed to handle multi-line comments; you would need something stateful like perl or awk.